# trying to convert a table image to WCAG approved HTML table

Tags: html, html-table, wcag

I've been trying to convert the supplement table to a WCAG approved HTML table for my website. I'm finding it hard to understand what should go in the table and under which heading it should go. I have attached an example; I have already created one but having trouble with another one. The components of the Probiotic Bacteria [(Supplement Table Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDFPA.jpg) Blend should be included or not? And if yes, how?

Comment: For reference, check this : https://wet-boew.github.io/wet-boew-legacy/v3.0/demos/tableparser/Table-CaseStudies-2.html

Answer (score 0):

In the particular case that you've linked, the Probiotic Bacteria Blend could be done in a couple of different ways. Remember that ultimately the most important thing is that the information is conveyed.

I recommend either keeping it the details of the Blend as part of the same description (in the same cell), so:

|  | Amount per serving | % DV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Probiotic Bacteria Blend Composed of the following strains: [the rest of the text] | 10 Billion Viable Cells (Minimum)✝ | Daily value not established |

Or make it an additional footnote:

|  | Amount per serving | % DV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Probiotic Bacteria Blend✝✝ | 10 Billion Viable Cells (Minimum)✝ | Daily value not established |

The one thing you don't want to do is have it in its own row since it's a description of the blend and doesn't have its own amount and percentage value.

Side note: For making the footnote accessible (which I haven't included), consider referring to the SO answer on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31254917/4131590